# How do you import your modified UI Modules in Android Studio to replace the ones used in the demo android app

Tags: mesibo

How do you import your modified UI Modules in Android Studio to replace the ones used in the demo android app that you can download from GitHub?

Thank you!

```
implementation "com.mesibo.api:uihelper:${project.MesiboVersion_UiHelper}"
implementation "com.mesibo.api:mesibo:${project.MesiboVersion_Api}"
implementation "com.mesibo.api:ui:${project.MesiboVersion_Ui}"
implementation "com.mesibo.api:callui:${project.MesiboVersion_CallUi}"
```

Comment: You need to remove those dependencies and replace them with your compiled module dependency.

Comment: Can you write a quick tutorial on how to do that?

Thank you very much!